# How can I extract xml file encoding using streamreader?

Tags: c#, xml, stream

I needed to get the encoding type from the top of the xml file

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>
```

but only the encoding="utf-8" is needed

the "utf-8" only without the quotation mark, how can I achieve this using streamreader?

Comment: You can ignore the first line of xml.  So I usually just use reader.ReadLine() which will skip the first line.  It is not the stream reader that is giving the error.  It is the XmlReader that is giving error.

Comment: If you load it into an XDocument you can ask .Declaration.Encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's xml, I would recommend [XmlTextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to XML data and read just top of the xml file since declaration is there. See following method:

```
string FindXmlEncoding(string path)
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
    reader.Read();
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    {
        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "encoding")
                return reader.Value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need **utf-8** or **encoding="utf-8"** ? this block returns **utf-8** as a result. If you need encoding="utf-8", you need to change.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"yourXmlFilePath"))
{
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };

    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
    {
        if (!xmlReader.Read()) throw new Exception("No line");

        var result = xmlReader.GetAttribute("encoding"); //returns utf-8

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I achieve this using `StreamReader`?

Something like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("XmlFile.xml"))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    int closeQuoteIndex = line.LastIndexOf("\"") - 1;
    int openingQuoteIndex = line.LastIndexOf("\"", closeQuoteIndex);
    string encoding = line.Substring(openingQuoteIndex + 1, closeQuoteIndex - openingQuoteIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const string ENCODING_TAG = "encoding"; //You are searching for this. Lets make it constant.


string line = streamReader.ReadLine();    //Use your reader here
int start = line.IndexOf(ENCODING_TAG);
start = line.IndexOf('"', start)+1;       //Start of the value
int end = line.IndexOf('"', start);       //End of the value
string encoding = line.Substring(start, end-start);
```

**NOTE:** This approach expects the encoding to be in the first line of an existing declaration. [Which it does not need to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#XML_declaration).